# how to send sms via a dual sim mobile using serial port

Tags: c#, modem, at-command

I am sending sms to recipients using following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var com5 = new SerialPort("COM5");
        if (!com5.IsOpen) com5.Open();
        com5.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
        com5.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
        com5.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + 03132449297 + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
        com5.WriteLine("Kashif bhai aap mujhsay kiya kehna chah rahay hen?" + (char)26);            
        com5.Close();                                  

    }
```

my problem is: If i use a single sim mobile usb modem to send sms using above mentioned coding it works fine. but when i use a dual sim mobile usb modem I am not able to send sms using above mentioned coding. I have tried nokia 200 and samsung gt-c3312

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting me though this problem is the genuine, and crystal clear. today the most of the mobiles have dual sim option. and above mentioned method for sending sms is really not working in a dual sim mobile. i acknowledge that in some dual sim mobile it is working e.g megagate the sms is being sent by sim one automatically. but what's wrong with the other ones e.g nokia 200 and samsung gt-c3312. if the downvoters think that this question is easy to be solved or it is useless why don't they solve it to take 50 reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try AT+CSIMSEL=1 ?

see 11.4 AT+CSIMSEL Switch between two SIM card in this document:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/63648056/186/AT-CSIMSEL-Switch-between-two-SIM-card

> The command is used to select external or embedded SIM card. NOTE
>
> 1. Embedded SIM card supported by customization. Customer should provide informationwritten into USIM chipset.
> 2. The command is disabled if the embedded SIM card isn’t exist, i.e. standard hardwareversion.
>
> Defined values
>
> 1 – external SIM card
>
> 2 – embedded SIM card

Answer (score 0):

try this if this works
http://wenku.baidu.com/view/f740bd000740be1e650e9a41.html?from=related
else there is no such command to send sms using a dual sim mobile..