# How to send AT Commands in Dual Sim Phone

Tags: c#, nokia, at-command, 32feet, dual-sim

how to send AT commands to a **dual sim** phone  ?
I tried `AT+CSIMSEL` in a C# Program (using 32feet library) but it don't work on my Nokia phone.
Thanks

Comment: I think device manufacturers have defined their own AT commands to choose the SIM.

Comment: Thanks but where can i found them ?

Comment: It would help is you added the Nokia model to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send sms via a dual sim mobile using serial port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106283/how-to-send-sms-via-a-dual-sim-mobile-using-serial-port)

Comment: nop i mentioned that the command CSIMSEL doesn't work

Comment: Is there any manual of AT commands available on the Nokia developers site?  Have you searched this site? If not, then the AT command that you need may not be publically available.  You could try AT+CLAC - if the phone supports that, then you get a list of supported AT commands, and you can investigate them.

Answer (score 0):

To send AT command to phone Modem your application process must run in phone process.

Android provided a API invokeOemRilRequestStrings to send AT command to Modem at Phone instance.

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone"
```

Manifest file tag

```
android:process="com.android.phone"
```

Under application tag

```
void SendAtToModem() {
    String s[] = new String[2];
    s[0] = "AT+XXXXX=" + "1";
```

AT command plus its value that you want to set

```
    s[1] = "";

    Phone[] phones = PhoneFactory.getPhones();
    phones[0].invokeOemRilRequestStrings(s, null);
```

To send at Modem 1

```
    phones[1].invokeOemRilRequestStrings(s, null);
```

To send at Modem 2